# Why is socket.sendall() not working?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

With my program, I am attempting to connect to a IP address using socket.socket(), and when it connects to capture a bit of morse code, decode it, and then push the answer back through the socket with socket.sendall(). I have it so I can connect to the IP address, decode the message, and even send back my answer, but when I send back the answer it says that it's wrong, even though I know for a fact it isn't. I'm wondering if maybe, when I'm sending back my answer, if I'm sending back an additional set of quotation marks around it or something? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import socket

def morse(code):
    decoded = []
    CODE = [['.-', 'A'],['-...', 'B'],['-.-.', 'C'],['-..', 'D'],['.', 'E'],['..-.', 'F'],['--.', 'G'],['....', 'H'],['..', 'I'],['.---', 'J'],['-.-', 'K'],['.-..', 'L'],['--', 'M'],['-.', 'N'],['---', 'O'],['.--.', 'P'],['--.-', 'Q'],['.-.', 'R'],['...', 'S'],['-', 'T'],['..-', 'U'],['...-', 'V'],['.--', 'W'],['-..-', 'X'],['-.--', 'Y'],['--..', 'A']]
    for i in CODE:
        if i[0] == code:
            decoded.append(i[1].lower())
        if code == '':
            decoded.append('.')
    return decoded

def netcat(hostname, port, content):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname, port))
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
            break
        if "text:" in repr(data):
            s.sendall(content)
        print("Received:", repr(data))
        if "-" in repr(data):
            splitMorse = repr(data).split(' ')
            splitMorse = splitMorse[8:len(splitMorse)-2]
            decoded = []
            for i in splitMorse:
                decoded.extend(morse(i))
            strDecoded = ''.join(decoded)
            strDecoded = strDecoded.replace("....................................................", " ")
            print("{}\n".format(strDecoded))
            #HERE IS WHERE I AM SENDING THE STRING BACK
            print(s.sendall("{}\n".format(strDecoded)))
    print("Connection closed.")
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    s.close()

content = "GET\n"
netcat('146.148.102.236', 24069, content)
```

At the end of sending my string through the socket, I added an "\n" because otherwise it won't accept my string and it'll sit there forever (because you have to press enter after typing. Here is my output:

```
('Received:', "'------------------------------------------\\nWelcome to 
The Neverending Crypto!\\nQuick, find Falkor and get through this!\\nThis
is level 1, the Bookstore\\nRound 1. Give me some text:'")


None
('Received:', "'GET encrypted is --. . - \\nWhat is ..-. .-. .- --. -- . 
-. - .- - .. --- -.  decrypted?\\n:'")
fragmentation

None
('Received:', "'No... I am leaving.\\n'")
Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic is flawed. The first message contains `text:` and it also contains `-`. I think you want `elif` for your final if.

For your sequence of `if` statements in `netcat()`, try this:

```
   if data == "":
        break
   print("Received:", repr(data))
   if "text:" in repr(data):
        ...
   elif "-" in repr(data):
        ...
```